# Split string before the number out of text with mix number and string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some string like this

```
"ABC17" , "ABCDE16", "AB17a",  "ABCDER10b"
```

I want to split the string that goes in front of the number out so the result is like

```
"17" , "16", "17a", "10b"
```

I also want to ask if my string has some special characters at the end such as

```
"ABC17)" , "ABCDE16", "AB17a]",  "ABCDER10b"
```

I want to split the string that goes in front of the number out and remove the ) or ] so the result is like

```
"17" , "16", "17a", "10b"
```

Is there a way to do this?

I have tried

```
string.split(/(\d+)/)[1]
```

but this only takes all of the letters out of the string. I only want to take the letter in front of the number out and keep the number and letter after the number, such as 10b.

Comment: `.replace(/^\D*/, '')`

Comment: It works though: https://jsfiddle.net/asdL36wq/

Comment: thanks! it works for the first part. I want to ask if my string has ) ], how can I get rid of those too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in a list you should be able to do this

```js
var x = ["ABC17" , "ABCDE16", "AB17a",  "ABCDER10b"]
x.forEach(y=>{console.log(y.replace(/^\D*/, ''))})
```

Comment: Also I would like to ask if my string has ) at the end such as "ABDC17a)", how can I get rid of the )

Comment: you can add an extra replace(')','')